# Where can I find a good checkbox app?

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation

I have recently started a job as a project manager. Equipped with an I pad I am currently going to site and taking photos of issues then manually writing out emails to associated colleagues. I was wondering if there is an app I can install with a check box system so I can easily yes/no each point and also add photos and write notes if need be. An app in which I could customise to suit questions eq Scaffholding around chimney sufficient... Yes/ no then being able to email report off to who ever I want would be great.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Punchlist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/punchlist/id422022727?mt=8) is the app to get. It's been around a while, the development is constant, rapid and ongiong. The price is very reasonable.